The site.USER_SITE/USER_BASE values are None when packaging a Kivy application with PyInstaller
I have a simple Kivy application, with some added KivyMD components. Here's my pip freeze output...
altgraph==0.17.4
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
configparser==7.1.0
Cython==3.0.0
docutils==0.21.2
idna==3.10
Kivy==2.3.0
kivy-deps.angle==0.4.0
kivy-deps.glew==0.3.1
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.7.0
Kivy-examples==2.3.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivy-translate==0.2.0
kivymd==1.2.0
macholib==1.16.3
modulegraph==0.19.6
packaging==24.2
pefile==2023.2.7
pillow==10.4.0
py2app==0.28.8
Pygments==2.18.0
pyinstaller==6.11.1
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2024.10
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==308
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.3
requests==2.32.3
urllib3==2.2.3

I have followed the instructions for packaging on Windows found here. I have already got a version working with MacOS, so using what I learned from that I tried to package for Windows.
Here's my main.spec file, which as per the Kivy docs, I run from a folder within my project folder, hence the ..\main.py usages:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy import kivy_data_dir
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path
block_cipher = None

# assets
kivy_assets_toc = Tree(kivy_data_dir, prefix=join('kivy_install', 'data'))
tocs = [kivy_assets_toc]

a = Analysis(
    ['..\\main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('..\\locale\\*', 'locale'),('..\\images\\*', 'images')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=["hook.py"],
    excludes=['_tkinter', 'Tkinter', 'enchant', 'twisted'],
    noarchive=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    Tree('..\\'),
    a.scripts,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    *tocs,
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    *tocs,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)


Which also has a hook.py that sets an environment variable:
import os
from os.path import join

# Required to fix OpenGL version bug when building in Windows
# where when running and freezing the application, the application cannot find the correct
# OpenGL version and fails. This forces it to work for the build...
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'

Now, once packaged and run, I get this error from angle and a similar one for sdl2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "kivymd\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "kivy\__init__.py", line 320, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "kivy_deps\angle\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen ntpath>", line 108, in join
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

This comes from the angle.__init__ and sdl2.__init__ code which looks like below, and uses site.USER_BASE and site.USER_SITE respectively. It fails on the join due to d being None when looking for site.USER_BASE
for d in [sys.prefix, site.USER_BASE]:
    p = join(d, 'share', 'sdl2', 'bin')
    if isdir(p):
        os.environ["PATH"] = p + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
        if hasattr(os, 'add_dll_directory'):
            os.add_dll_directory(p)
        dep_bins.append(p)


It turns out that site.USER_BASE and site.USER_SITE are None when packaged. From what I am reading here is that they now mock out the site package.
Maybe my knowledge of python isn't great, but surely we need these set within a python application for packages to find python base and the site-packages?
I can optionally overwrite the values in my main.py file before the rest of the packages are imported, but not sure what they should be set to when within an executable? Note that when I add the following the executable builds, but running it fails with no error message. It just seems to crash. Understandably as i've set these to an empty string.
import site
if site.USER_SITE is None:
    site.USER_SITE = ""

if site.USER_BASE is None:
    site.USER_BASE = ""

Is this impossible given that PyInstaller mocks the site import? Anyone else been successful with this?

When you set an environment variable, it must be set very early in the execution, otherwise it has no effect. At the very top of your main.py you can use if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): to determine if your app is running as a Pyinstaller product. Then you can do the os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2' in that block.
